# Set and get checked boxes in MultiSelectListPreference

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm defining the `MultiSelectListPreference` in my axml file like this:

```
 <MultiSelectListPreference
        android:title="Title"
        android:summary="Sum"
        android:key="dutyMarks"
        android:entries="@array/array_marks"
        android:entryValues="@array/array_marksValues">
 </MultiSelectListPreference>
```

How can check / read the checked boxes in code?

I tried to get the checked values via the `PreferenceChange` event:

[image: preference change]

The checked values appear there, but I have no idea how to get them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This was also my first thought, but e.NewValue doesn't contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.

We can simply cast `e.NewValue` from `object` to `IEnumerable` in our code, for example:

```
private void PreferenceChange(object sender, Preference.PreferenceChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var selections = e.NewValue as IEnumerable;
    if (selections != null)
    {
        foreach (var selection in selections)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(selection);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since e.NewValue is a HashSet, you should be able to iterate through it

```
foreach (string x in e.NewValue) {
  // do whatever you need to do with each value x here
}
```

Comment: This was also my first thought, but e.NewValue doesn't contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles across this question, here is how i solved it:

**Read (the async part is pretty ugly, but I don't know how to add a 'preferenceChangeD' event)**

```
private async void preferenceChange(object sender, Preference.PreferenceChangeEventArgs e)
{
     await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100);

     List<string> sList = new List<string>();
     ICollection<string> selectedValues = mslp_dutyMarks.Values;
     foreach(string x in selectedValues)
          sList.Add(x);
}
```

**Write**

```
mslp_dutyMarks.Values = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
```

Comment: There is no need to do this, it is simple that we need to cast `e.NewValue` from `object` to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT is right var list = e.NewValue as Enumerable; is a better choice in this situation.